# Python "with" statement is throwing error

Tags: python, with-statement

Here is a sample code :

```py
class test :
    def __init__(self, text) :
        self.text = text
    def __enter__(self) :
        print("some text" + self.text)
    def __exit__(self, *args) :
        self.text = None
        print(args)
        return True

with test("hello world") :
    pass
with test(12) :
    pass
```

I use string concatenation in the `__enter__` function so that if the text argument is an int, a `TypeError` will occur (but should not be thrown because of the with statement)

From [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

> If an error occurs during the assignment to the target list, it will be treated the same as an error occurring within the suite would be.

> If the suite was exited due to an exception, and the return value from the **exit**() method was false, the exception is reraised. If the return value was true, the exception is suppressed, and execution continues with the statement following the with statement.

So here `__exit__` return True so why when I run this sample code, an error is thrown ?

Thank you for helping

Comment: `__exit__` isn't even reached because `__enter__` doesn't complete successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example in your code never calls the `__exit__` method because the `__enter__` method raises an error.  All of the error handling that gets passed to `__exit__` happens in the code block after `__enter__` **completes**.